# R- How to get mean/median/sd of non-NA intervals for different columns?

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the "non-NA values interval" for different columns.

Here is the dataset:

```
temp <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = 'month', length.out = 12),
  X1 = c(100, NA, 23, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100),
  X2 = runif(12, 50, 100),
  X3 = c(24, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31, 1, NA, 44, NA, 100, NA),
  X4 = NA
)
```

For example, `X1` has non-NA intervals as `1, 2, 5`, which means, from 100 to 23, there is 1 NA between these two non-NA values, from 23 to 12, there is 2 NAs between these two non-NA values, and from 12 to 100, there are 5 NAs between these two non-NA values.

The expected result is:

```
result <- data.frame(
  X1_inv_mean = mean(c(1, 2, 5)),
  X1_inv_median = median(c(1, 2, 5)),
  X1_inv_sd = sd(c(1, 2, 5)),

  X2_inv_mean = mean(0),
  X2_inv_median = median(0),
  X2_inv_sd = sd(0),

  X3_inv_mean = mean(c(4, 1, 1, 1)),
  X3_inv_median = median(c(4, 1, 1, 1)),
  X3_inv_sd = sd(c(4, 1, 1, 1)),

  X4_inv_mean = NA,
  X4_inv_median = NA,
  X4_inv_sd = NA
)

>result
  X1_inv_mean X1_inv_median X1_inv_sd X2_inv_mean X2_inv_median X2_inv_sd X3_inv_mean X3_inv_median X3_inv_sd
1    2.666667             2  2.081666           0             0        NA        1.75             1       1.5
  X4_inv_mean X4_inv_median X4_inv_sd
1          NA            NA        NA
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The result is not necessarily the exact same as the post, just with a similar outcome will be appreciated.

Comment: *X1 has non-NA intervals as 1, 2, 5*...why?? What do you mean with *non-NA intervals*?

Comment: Note that for `X4` there are 12 consecutive `NA`s and your desired output is thus not correct (assuming that I understood you correctly).

Comment: @Sotos, I have updated the post, so hopefully, I explained this better to you.

Comment: @markus For `X4` yes I expect it be `NA` for the ALL-NA column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option

```
out <- lapply(temp[-1], function(x) {
  if(all(is.na(x))) {
    tmp <- NA
  } else {
    tmp <- with(rle(is.na(x)), lengths[values])
    c(mean = mean(tmp),
      median = median(tmp),
      sd = sd(tmp))}
  })

as.data.frame(out)
#             X1  X2   X3 X4
#mean   2.666667 NaN 1.75 NA
#median 2.000000  NA 1.00 NA
#sd     2.081666  NA 1.50 NA
```

Using `rle` the following line gives you the runs of `NA`s for each column

```
tmp <- with(rle(is.na(x)), lengths[values])
```

E.g. for column `X1`

```
with(rle(is.na(temp$X1)), lengths[values])
#[1] 1 2 5
```

Then we calculate your summary statistics for each `tmp`.

If all values in a column are `NA` the function returns `NA`.

Comment: I get the result for the original dataset. The answer is perfect! Here I have an additional question, what is the mean of this `lengths[values]` ? I understand `with()` and its arguments, also, the result of `rle` gives a list contains `lengths` and `values`, but I cannot connect the result of rle to this `lengths[values]`. Thank you!

Comment: @J.D As you noted, `rle()` returns an object with two components: `lengths` and `values`. In above example, the latter is a logical vector. The usage of `with` allows you to evaluate these components in a local environment. That is, we don't need to assign the result of `rle` to a name first and latter manipulate its values, we can do it in one go. Since `values` is of type logical, what `lengths[values]` does returns only those values of `lengths` for which `values` is `TRUE`. The same as `r <- rle(is.na(temp$X1)); r$lengths[r$values]` - just nicer to read for interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
For variable n columns:

```
command <- ""
summaryString <- ""
for(i in colnames(temp)){
     if(i != "date"){
       print(i)
       summaryString <- paste(summaryString,i,"_inv_mean = mean(",i,", na.rm = T),",sep="")
       summaryString <- paste(summaryString,i,"_inv_median = median(",i,", na.rm = T),",sep="")
       summaryString <- paste(summaryString,i,"_inv_sd = sd(",i,", na.rm = T),",sep="")
     }

   command <- paste("output <- temp %>% summarise(",substr(summaryString, 0, nchar(summaryString)-1),")",sep="")
}

eval(parse(text=command))
```

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
output <- temp%>%
  summarise(x1_inv_mean = mean(X1, na.rm = T),
        x1_inv_median = median(X1, na.rm = T),
        x1_inv_sd = sd(X1, na.rm = T),
        x2_inv_mean = median(X2, na.rm = T),
        x2_inv_median = mean(X2, na.rm = T),
        x2_inv_sd = sd(X2, na.rm = T),
        x3_inv_mean = median(X3, na.rm = T),
        x3_inv_median = mean(X3, na.rm = T),
        x3_inv_sd = sd(X3, na.rm = T),
        x4_inv_mean = mean(X4, na.rm = T),
        x4_inv_median = median(X4, na.rm = T),
        x4_inv_sd = sd(X4, na.rm = T))
```